# Bitrock Installer on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, installation, bitrock

Daniel Lopez wrote that there is code in Bitrock for checking permissions. I have looked in the knowledge Base, but couldn't find the necessary code.  Anyone know?
Also, what about code for changing privileges?
Thanks in advance,
Roger Mester

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the Apple documents for [chmod](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) command or the [chmod](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html) system call.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I do not believe this questions belongs to Stack Overflow, please contact our support directly next time, we will be glad to help you there)

You can take a look at the [changePermissions](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide.html#__changepermissions) and [changeOwnerAndGroup](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide.html#__changeownerandgroup) actions, they do what you require